# OpenGL GLSL texture transparency

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glsl, transparency

I want to make transparency on my 32bit bitmap texture using GLSL.
My fragment shader looks like this:

```
#version 120
uniform sampler2D myTexture;
varying vec2 TexCoord;

void main(void)
{
    if(texture2D(myTexture, TexCoord).a != 1.0f)
    {
        discard;
    }
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(myTexture, TexCoord);
}
```

But that makes transparent only the pixels where alpha is equal 0 and **I want to maintain the fade** from the texture. For example in this picture the first image is the texture, the second is the texture mask and the third is the desired result:

[image: Example]

The texture and the texture mask are in one 32bit bitmap.

Does anyone know, how to achieve this using GLSL?

Comment: This is achieved by blending. https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm

Comment: I know, but that's the immediate mode only and it's really inaccurate, I want to do it with shaders. The blending also makes some annoying transparent border around the mask.

Comment: Blending  does work well with shaders and modern OpengGL.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to enable `GL_BLEND`, and the alpha output of your fragment shader will be used to blend the fragment output with the framebuffer.

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(..., ...);

glDraw????(...);

// You don't have to do it here, but GL_BLEND will remain enabled
// until you disable it again.
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

If you use premultiplied alpha,

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

If you use non-premultiplied alpha,

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

The fragment shader can't do the blending because it doesn't have access to the framebuffer.

Comment: Ok thank you, can you tell me please, how can I get rid of the residue of the texture so it can be seen through on objects behing the texture? In this picture http://i.imgur.com/QDmXb0z.png?1 you can see a slider bar and the caret. The transparency is on the caret, but the bar is not visible through the alpha pixels. Why?

Comment: Yes... if you draw transparent objects, you can't use ordinary depth testing, you have to sort the objects and draw back-to-front (unless you use order-independent transparency, but most people don't).  A typical scene will start with the solid objects (front-to back, for better performance) followed by the transparent objects, which must be back-to-front.